# How to use case statment in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have this situation here in SQL where I need to display dr_DRVNUM, DR_DRVNAME & number of days worked for drivers who have worked the same shift on multiple days.

I have this code in SQL,  I also try different code so far but still not any luck

```
select dr_drvname, dr_drvnum, sh_wkdate
case  when sh_drvnum = dr_drvnum and sh_wkshift = 'DAY' then count(sh_wkdate)
end 
from driver, shift
```

I have a table I am uploading a part of the table image below,

```
DR_DRVNUM      DR_DRVNAME           SH_WKDATE        SH_WKSHIFT 

0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        EVE
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        EVE
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        EVE
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        NIG
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        NIG
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  15-NOV-07        NIG
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        DAY
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        EVE
0001           Cooper, Randolph B.  16-NOV-07        EVE
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Did Cooper have several day shifts on e.g. 15-NOV-07 or should those count as one shift? If one, why duplicate rows?

Comment: Thank you Guys I figured it out. BTW what i was trying to do is if cooper work more than one day on the safe shift ex"DAY, OR EVE OR NIG" then it's count number of days if he works on 15 nov Day/NIG/EVE shift only then fucntion does not count ANYTHING

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand what you're looking for.  When using `count` with other fields, you should be utilizing the `group by` clause.  It also sounds like you should be using `count` with `case` like this:

```
select 
    dr_drvname, 
    dr_drvnum,
    sh_wkdate,
    count(case when sh_wkshift = 'DAY' then 1 end)
from driver d
    left join shift s on s.sh_drvnum = d.dr_drvnum
group by
    dr_drvname, 
    dr_drvnum,
    sh_wkdate
```

BTW -- this uses an `outer join` to join the driver and shift tables to return all drivers, even if they have no shifts.  Depending on your desired results, you may be good with just an `inner join`.

Comment: thank you for your help. for example like cooper worked on day shift on 15-nov-07 and same shift on 17-nov-07. i have a table that have 15 to 18 nov. what i need if cooper works for day shift on each day it says 4, if he works 3 day shift on three days it says 3 and it works the same way for "NIG" OR "EVE"